# Since April 1st upload to Crashlytics Beta fails

Tags: firebase, crashlytics, google-fabric, fabric-beta

We are using Jenkins Pipelines with a pipeline script and the Fabric Beta Publisher step.
Since April 1st the step fails, but no other error is visible. 
Was part of Fabric/Crashlytics still disabled on April 1st? (Although the migration phase was extended to may? )

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to migrate to [Firebase App Distribution](https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-distribution). Have not looked for the exact shutdown date, but in case it doesn't work anymore, one probably can assume to be already past that date. It is irrelevant when the deadline ***was***. (this site is all about the technical aspect, not  contract terms).

See these articles for how to setup with Jenkins:

- [Firebase app distribution during fabric to firebase migration — The Jenkins Way](https://medium.com/@kiitvishal89/firebase-app-distribution-during-fabric-to-firebase-migration-the-jenkins-way-3a43ac172e9d)
- [Setting up Firebase App Distribution With Automatic Builds from Jenkins](https://medium.com/velos/setting-up-firebase-app-distribution-with-automatic-builds-from-jenkins-2587028e2a3a)

Comment: It was clear, that we have to migrate. But due to the corona crisis, we postponed some changes to our CI system, that also involve upgrade of the machines. We thought that the changed date that was announced by Fabric included that all API is functional up to May, and we have some more time for the upgrade. But it seems we were wrong, unfortunately.

Comment: Thanks for posting the guides